# Google AdSense bot's algorithm and behavior?

Tags: google-adsense

I am interested in Google AdSense bot's algorithm and behavior with web sites. I did not work with AdSense and I do not have account so I need your help to understand:

1) Gbot from time to time downloads all pages from web site.

Am I right?

2) Gbot do not understand dynamic content (loaded by Ajax).

So I must generate static content and return it within HTML page and this page must show identical content for all users and for Gbot?

3) Because of (1) and (2) I cannot use only root path http://example.com with some "main" widget.

I must generate unique pages for example `http://example.com/thread?id=101`?

4) Gbot downloads pages (1) for grabbing (indexing) keywords from them and then store (on its servers) the information for example by key/value (where key is page path, value is tag cloud).

Am I right?

5) When web site has been opened in browser by user. Integrated HTML AdSense's code loads some JavaScript. As I understand by "googling" this JavaScript does not index page but makes call (with some parameter key==page_path) to Google's server and gets appropriate ad links. Then shows these ad links in its frame.

Is it right behavior?

Maybe JavaScript makes some local indexing of page's content?

6) How do Gbot and AdSense's JavaScript work with cookies?

As I understand AdSense can use cookies for showing appropriate ad links.

If this is right, please give me some use cases.

I know that "true" algorithm is known only by engineers from Google but some of you had experience with AdSense and AdSense HTML/JavaScript.

Please correct my vision of it ;)

Comment: Please, post each question in a separate thread.

Comment: This sounds like it would be more appropriate for [Webmasters](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> 1) Gbot from time to time downloads
>   all pages from web site. Am i right?

The bot attempts to download a page as soon as it is requested for the first time. Then, it will try to keep the content of the page up-to-date by accessing it periodically.

Google uses a `shared cache`. Because Google has several bot (AdSense, Google Crawler, ...), the most update cache will be used by AdSense. This feature minimizes the impact of Google bot on your site.

> 2) Gbot do not understand dynamic
>   content (loaded by ajax). So i must
>   generate static content and return it
>   within html page and this pages must
>   show identical content for all users
>   and for Gbot?

I don't know whether it's a good idea. However, I can confirm AdSense bot can't show ads based on content loaded from AJAX.

> 3) Because of (1) and (2) i cannot use
>   only root path http://example.com with
>   some "main" widget. I must generate
>   unique pages for example
>   http://example.com/thread?id=101 ?

It can be helpful. Avoid using parameters like id or sessionid. Rewrite the URL, if you can. eg. http://example.com/thread/101

> 4) Gbot downloads pages (1) for
>   grabbing (indexing) keywords from them
>   and then store (on it's servers) these
>   information for example by key/value
>   (where key is page path, value is tag
>   cloud). Am i right?

Who knows? I mean, you have to be a Google engineer to know how Google stores its data. Why does information is it important for you? BTW, this is not really that simple. One example is the "shared cache" feature I described before.

> 5) When web site has been opened in
>   browser by user. Integrated html
>   AdSense's code loads some JavaScript.
>   As i understand by "googling" this
>   JavaScript do not index page, but
>   makes call (with some parameter
>   key==page_path) to Google's server and
>   gets appropriate ad links. Then shows
>   this ad links in it's frame. Is it
>   right behavior? Maybe JavaScript makes
>   some local indexing of page's content?

The JavaScript simply displays the ads. It also notifies Google about the existence of the page, if it still doesn't know about it. In this case, an AdSense bot will crawl the content in about 2 seconds.

> 6) How Gbot and AdSense's JavaScript
>   work with cookies? As i understand
>   AdSense can use cookies for show
>   appropriate ad links. If it is right,
>   please give me some use cases;)

It's better to have cookies enabled.